# default value on dropdown from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to show default values on my dropdown from a database table.

This is my html code:

```html
<div class="POScounter">
  <div class="form-group counter">
    <label>Counter :</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="CounterDropdown"></select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group pricing">
    <label>Pricing Level :</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="PricingLevelDropdown"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group pricing">
    <label>Mode:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Modedropdown"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the values in my table:

```
Id  |SettingName |  settingNamevalue
1   |mode        |  cash
2   |PricingLevel|  test1
3   |Counter     |  counter1
```

Comment: You have to fill the dropdown lists at first.Pls show how you do this.

Comment: How are you communicating with the server? You need to show us more code and  where you got stuck.

Comment: I have loaded the dropdown from its individual table. here what I want to do is give privilege to user to set default on these dropdown, so I created a different table name setting to store those data and I need to assign default values on these boxes